# How can we do energy balance in this problem if friction is present and changing?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, spring

[image]
A uniform cylinder of mass M and radius R rolls without slipping down a slope of
angle a(theta) to the horizontal. The cylinder is connected to a spring constant K while
the other end of the spring is connected to a rigid support at P The cylinder is
released when the spring is unstretched. The maximum distance that the cylinder
travels is?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" questions.

Comment: Hello there, as fellow users have pointed out, that stack exchange isn't a simple, check my homework like site. I would suggest you try the problem yourself and then ask the community, the concepts due to which you get stuck

Comment: I have found the answer and I am only asking the concept , I have neither asked anyone to provide the solution nor  to find my mistake, the question below is only for reference.

Comment: The question isn't asking the how can you solve? But its how is its possible that this has happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The friction in this situation is static friction. It provides a torque which causes an angular acceleration (first positive and later negative), but it does not dissipate energy.

Comment: But why is the friction static and not kinetic

Comment: For a cylinder rolling freely on a surface, at the point of contact, the cylinder is not moving relative to the surface. (Consider the bottom of a wheel on your car.) There may be a small "rolling friction" associated with the deformation of the surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Friction always acts to oppose the actual or impending motion.  The **maximum** frictional force in this case is the coefficient of sliding friction times the normal force.  However, this maximum frictional force occurs when the mass slips; for rolling without slipping, the frictional force is less and may not be constant.  You can search this exchange for more details on friction; for example see [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509358/why-do-the-expressions-for-an-object-rolling-down-an-incline-not-depend-on-the-c?r=SearchResults&s=2|46.4439](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509358/why-do-the-expressions-for-an-object-rolling-down-an-incline-not-depend-on-the-c?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C46.4439). Also, The Halliday and Resnick physics textbooks discuss this.