# Clarification on friction coefficient for a mass rolling down an incline

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, friction

I have been working on the following AP Physics 1 free-response question:

> 1974M2.  The moment of inertia of a uniform solid sphere (mass $M$, radius $R$)  is $\frac{2}{5}MR^2$.   The sphere is placed on an inclined plane (angle $θ$) and released from rest. Determine the minimum coefficient of friction $μ$ between the sphere and plane with which the sphere will roll down the incline without slipping.

I understand that the torque in this case is a result of static friction. I have performed the following work so far:

$$\sum I = \frac{2}{5}MR^2$$
$$\sum \tau = I\alpha = \frac{2}{5}MRa_t$$
$$\sum \tau = \mu F_NR = \mu Mgcos{\theta}R$$
$$a_t = \frac{5}{2}\mu gcos{\theta}$$

I know that the next step is to substitute $a_t$ into $\sum F = Ma_t$ but am struggling when it comes to defining what forces make up $\sum F$. My first instinct was for
$$\sum F = Mgsin{\theta}$$

but the answer key that I looked at also took into account the frictional force in computing $$\sum F = Mgsin{\theta} - \mu Mgcos{\theta}$$

This doesn't make sense to me because I would effectively be solving for the kinetic frictional coefficient but the question is asking for the friction that causes the sphere to roll, which I believe to be static. I understand how there would be kinetic friction, but don't see how it relates back to the question.

I think there's clearly something I'm misunderstanding. Could someone help clarify what's going on here?

Comment: Related question: [Can we know when rolling occurs without slipping?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/470572/179151)

Comment: @hiccups I just revisited the problem after a brain break and can understand how this is not kinetic friction at play since the sphere is not sliding. Just to clarify, however, when you're calculating F = ma like in the equation above, since it is a rolling motion, then should you treat static frictional force as though it's a continuous force?

Comment: In Newtonian mechanics, Newton's laws hold for all forces. Why do you think static friction is different here?